# Showing xtrareport report with subreports with scripts and charts in diff detailreports corrupts charts

Tags: charts, devexpress, xtrareport, subreports

I have a report that shows a collection of tests. The test report is actually another xtrareport that is shown as a subreport in the collection report. In these testreports there can be multiple subtests and. For each subtest there is a chart that is created in a script.
This is the script to create a graph for the subtest:

```
private void xrChart1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) 
{
    XRChart chrt = (XRChart)sender;
    XYDiagram axis = (XYDiagram)chrt.Diagram;
    if (chrt.Series.Count > 0)
    {
        while (chrt.Series[0].View is ScatterLineSeriesView)
        {
            chrt.Series.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
    Series standardSeries = chrt.Series[0];
    Series allBottleSeries = chrt.Series[1];
      var curColVal = this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("ShowCurve");
      if (curColVal == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    chrt.BeginInit();
    chrt.Visible = (bool)curColVal;
    if (chrt.Visible)
    {
        List<TSegment> segments = (List<TSegment>)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("Segments");
        if (segments != null)
        {
            foreach (TSegment segment in segments)
            {
                Series tempSeries = new Series();
                ScatterLineSeriesView tempscatterLineSeriesView = new ScatterLineSeriesView();
                tempscatterLineSeriesView.LineMarkerOptions.BorderVisible = false;
                tempscatterLineSeriesView.MarkerVisibility = DefaultBoolean.False;
                tempscatterLineSeriesView.LineStyle.Thickness = segment.Thickness;
                tempscatterLineSeriesView.Color = segment.SegmentColor;
                tempSeries.LabelsVisibility = DefaultBoolean.False;
                tempSeries.View = tempscatterLineSeriesView;
                tempSeries.ShowInLegend = false;
                tempSeries.ArgumentDataMember = "X";
                tempSeries.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
                tempSeries.ValueDataMembersSerializable = "Y";
                tempSeries.DataSource = segment.Points;
                chrt.Series.Insert(0, tempSeries);
            }
        }
        standardSeries.ValueDataMembers[0] = "ODValue";
        standardSeries.ArgumentDataMember = "ConcentrationValue";
        standardSeries.DataSource = this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("Standards");
        allBottleSeries.ValueDataMembers[0] = "Y";
        allBottleSeries.ArgumentDataMember = "X";
        allBottleSeries.DataSource = this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("BottlePoints");
        axis.AxisX.Logarithmic = (bool)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("XPlotIsLog");
        axis.AxisX.LogarithmicBase = (double)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("LogarithmicBase");
        axis.AxisX.Title.Text = (string)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("UnitsOfConcentration");
        axis.AxisX.Label.NumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Number;
        axis.AxisX.Label.NumericOptions.Precision = (int)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("NumberOfDigitsInResults");
        axis.AxisY.Label.NumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Number;
        axis.AxisY.Label.NumericOptions.Precision = (int)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("NumberOfDigitsInMeasuredValues");
        axis.AxisY.Logarithmic = (bool)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("YPlotIsLog");
        axis.AxisY.LogarithmicBase = axis.AxisX.LogarithmicBase;
            axis.AxisY.Title.Text = (string)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("UnitsOfStandardsInput");
        axis.AxisY.WholeRange.AlwaysShowZeroLevel = !(bool)this.DetailReport1.GetCurrentColumnValue("ODAxisShouldNotStartAtZero");
    }
    chrt.EndInit();

}
```

Now if I look at this subreport separately the report is shown correctly. The different subtests have a different chart.

The problem is when I show the collection report the the subreport is shown wrongly. All the charts are not different. The chart of the last subtest is shown all the time instead.

This script is used to set the reportsource of the subreports:

```
private void Detail1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) 
{
    ((XRSubreport)sender).ReportSource = this.DetailReport.GetCurrentRow() as XtraReport;
}
```

Anyone any ideas of what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this issue.
It actually had nothing to do with the scripts.
The object we binded the collection report to has a property called TestXtrareports which is a List of XtraReport.
When we create this object we've called CreateDocument on the XtraReport before we've added it to TestXtraReports. 
This is what caused this bug. Just deleting the createDocument statement of the XtraReports in TestXtraReports solved it.
CreateDocument is still called on the collection report.